# Error : file not found in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, access

I have a problem of error "file not found" in a site collection SharePoint 2010.

- I cannot access to home page, the page of list/library/permission,etc. All pages will appear an error "file not found"
- I can access to the page of "all content"
- I can access to the site setting page, but I cannot open the link on this page. For example, I select "quick launch" in "Look and feel" section, it will show an error "file not found".
- I think I must reset my master page, but I cannot use SharePoint Designer (forbidden in my application), I cannot open the link on site setting page, and I cannot open library page to check the master page
- I can access to mobile view, and all pages work well in mobile view, but I did not find site setting page

How could I check the master page? 
Or this problem has other solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the ULS logs to identify what file is not found.

To reset the masterpage, do it with powershell. eg:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://sharepoint
$web.CustomMasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/nightandday.master"
$web.MasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/nightandday.master"
$web.Update()
```

Once you've identified the missing file and resolved, load your custom one back in. You may have to iterate a few times to get it right.

Comment: Thank your advice. I reset the master page with powershell

Answer (score 0):

You have to sett alternate access mapping in central admin to access SharePoint Portal both using hostname and IP.

Here is the tutorial with picture :
[Configure Alternate Access Mapping](http://menetes.blogspot.co.id/2016/03/site-permission-and-site-setting-error.html)